# Logging into an asp.net site from web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, meteor

Ok. I've looked around and around, but, I can't find the answers I'm looking for, assuming they exist.
My project has 2 halves to it. One half, I've built myself, the other half was built (I'm fairly sure) in ASP.NET-MVC by another developer, I only have access to the codebase for my half, but, I have credentials to log into the second.
I want to be able to scrape the site from my server, logged in with my credentials, but, I'm not sure A. If it's possible, or B. How to do it. Everything I've tried so far has resulted in a certain "__RequestVerificationToken" cookie not being present.

Current Code:

```
HTTP.post('URLtoASP.NETlogin', {
  data: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    __RequestVerificationToken: HTTP.get('URLtoASP.Netresource') //Results in the token from the hidden field from the login page
  }
}, (err, res)=>{
  console.log(err ? err : res)
})
```

The exact error given is: "The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."